# Split 200MB textfile with delimiter-line in PHP

Tags: php, split

I need to split a big text-file (200MB) into multiple smaller files. The split should be based on a defined text-line.

**Big file**

```
This is a title
Lorem Ipsum
New Chapter
This is a title
Lorem Ipsum
```

So the line `This is a title` should mark where to split the file and it also should be the first line of the new file. So the result would be:

**First file**

```
This is a title
Lorem Ipsum
New Chapter
```

**Second file**

```
This is a title
Lorem Ipsum
```

I can split the textfile into defined byte-sizes, but this is not, what I need:

```
$i = 1;
$fp = fopen("big_file.txt",'r');
while(! feof($fp)) {
    $contents = fread($fp,1000);
    file_put_contents($i.'.txt',$contents);
    $i++;
}
```

I need to split for a defined line.

Comment: If doing it for a defined line, you need to read the file line by line, test the value of that line, and close old writing file/open new writing file as appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go line by line and search for the delimiter:

```
$i = 1;
$file = fopen("big_file.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    if ($line == "delimiter") {
        if ($contents) file_put_contents($i.'.txt',$contents);
        $contents = '';
        $i++;
    }
    else $contents .= $contents;
}
fclose($file);
```