# Split text file into multiple files based on <END> in PHP

Tags: php

I am struggling to create a PHP script to help split a large text file into multiple smaller files based on `<END>` tag. I need the option to increment the split, so it starts before `<END>` tag on the first file, next file after `<END>` tag to before `<END>` tag on the second and so on.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please edit your question and post the code you already have (perferably along with some example).

Comment: which I have try to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963215/split-200mb-textfile-with-delimiter-line-in-php

Comment: Could you please add code of your script?

Comment: its solve.`<?php
$i =1;
$fp = fopen('Portfolio.sor','r');
//$fileName = $line[1];
while(! feof($fp)) {
    /*
file separet by <END> tag
*/
    $contents = stream_get_line($fp,false,'<END>');
    file_put_contents('temp/'.'file_name'.$i,$contents);
    $i++;
}

fclose($fp);`